# Can NHibernate produce SQL that is not commented with param names?

Tags: nhibernate

Is it possible to configure NHibernate to *not* show the parameter names in comments, in the SQL it produces?

E.g.

```
WHERE  shareclass1_.PeerGroupId in (1 /* @p0 */,8 /* @p1 */,7 /* @p2 */,10 /* @p3 */,
                                   20 /* @p4 */,2 /* @p5 */)
```

It makes the SQL very unreadable.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting "use_sql_comments" to false. Using Fluent NHibernate's configuration:

```
var factory = Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(configurer)
                .Mappings(m =>  /* etc */)
                .ExposeConfiguration(configuration =>
                                     configuration
                                         .SetProperty(Environment.UseSqlComments, "false"))
                .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: is this possible using the 'old fashioned' non-fluent way?

Comment: Sure, just set the key/value properties or do it in code. http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/07/17/nhibernate-configuration.aspx     -- Although, right now I can't test if this works for your problem, so do update. :)